# Conditional function based on label foreground color

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get output based on foreground color of a label.

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Style

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

class TestMe:
    def __init__(self):
        score_labels = {}
        score_names = ["score1", "score2", "score3"]

        s=Style()
        s.configure('score.TLabel', borderwidth=5, relief="solid",
                    font=('Helvetica', '12', 'bold'))
        for name in score_names:
            # Initialize score_name labels
            Label(root, text=name, style='score.TLabel', width=10,
                 ).grid(row=score_names.index(name), column=0)
            # Initialize score lables
            score_label = Label(root, text="", style='score.TLabel', width=3,
                                anchor='center')
            score_label.grid(row=score_names.index(name), column=1)            
            score_label.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_left_click)
            score_label.bind('<Button-3>', self.on_right_click)
            # Add score label to score_labels dictionary by score_name
            score_labels[name] = score_label
        # Set text and foreground color
        score_labels["score1"].config(text="0", foreground='red')
        score_labels["score2"].config(text="1", foreground='black')

    def on_left_click(self, event):
        if event.widget["text"]:
            print(event.widget["foreground"])

    def on_right_click(self, event):
        if event.widget["foreground"] == 'red':
            print(event.widget["foreground"])
        else:
            print("foo")          

TestMe()
root.mainloop()
```

Now, when i first right click on the 'score1' score label (the "0") i expect 'red' but i get 'foo'.

But when i first left click (and get 'red' as expected) and then right-click THEN i get 'red' from the right click.

Why do i need to left click first in order to make right click give me the correct value?

How to make right click output 'red' on the first try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because what the widget stores as the red value is not a typical string but a tkinter object.

First, convert the value returned by `event.widget["foreground"]` to a string. So, Replace

```
if event.widget["foreground"] == 'red':
```

With

```
if str(event.widget["foreground"]) == 'red':
```

Comment: Converting to string makes sense and it works, thank you!  Can you explain why, without the conversion, the right click only works after a left click?

Comment: I tried reproducing that, but was unable to. So I am not sure.

Comment: I accepted @nikost answer because converting to string solves the issue. However, i'm still curious on why the code in on_right_click() does work without conversion, but only after on_left_click() has been executed once for the label with foreground=red. Knowing the proposed solution, you'd expect it to not work at all. Yet it does. If anyone can elaborate, please do. The code i posted should be a fully working example of the issue.